# Granting read/write to all members in a role

Tags: sharing, role-hierarchy

I'm sure there's a way to do this but can't quite figure it out.  I have a custom object, and want access to it controlled by the role hierarchy.  However, I want everyone at the same role as the owner, or any role above that, to have both read and write access to the record.  What settings do I need do do that?  I think I can do this by creating a sharing rule for every node in the hierarchy, but that seems excessive.

Thx,
Hamayoun

Comment: you can use  Grant Access Using Hierarchies  :- https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_controlling_access_using_hierarchies.htm&language=en_US

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this sort of sharing model requires manually creating sharing rules for owners in each role to other users in that role.  The share via hierarchy setting is intended to share up the hierarchy, but doesn't provide options for sharing within the hierarchy.

This sort of sharing setup is fairly common, although it's typically implemented at one level in the role hierarhcy.  For example, if you can imagine a CEO role, with Sales VP roles for NA/EMEA/APAC beneath him, and a variety of Sales Roles beneath that.  In that case, you'd set up sharing rules to share all records owned by Sales VP NA Role and Subordinates to the Sales VP NA Role and Subordinates.  You might consider if this sort of setup would work for you.

Alternatively, if you're willing to write APEX you can programmatically handle the sharing, but it won't be trivial since you'll either have to create groups for each role as the target for the sharing, or share to individual users which then requires managing the sharing changes when a record is created, the owner changes, as well as user creation and role changes ...